# How to dynamically create an array of buttons in React using MonogoDB?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mongodb, mern

Im trying to convert my static product configurator into a dynamic one using the MERN stack, and I am really close to being done with the test version finally! I have everything working, but I am having trouble making it even more dynamic. In my configurator [here](https://cashcredenza.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html) for example, I have the ability to change colors through a list of hard coded buttons that trigger an event. This gets tedious with the amount of products that I will be trying to deploy to our website, and some products are only available in one, two, or three materials. I have successfully uploaded an array to MongoDB and is structured like so: [image][image][image]

So my main question is, how would I go about generating a list of buttons that are nested inside of an accordion like in my example above, while each "section" of the accordion would have the correlating name of that material selection.

Here is my hardcoded snipit of the HTML as well as some of the functions I have currently:

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";

// Actions
import {getProductDetails} from "../redux/actions/productActions";

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails);
  const {loading, error, product} = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
    }
    setCurrentSrc(product.src)
  }, [dispatch, match, product]);

  const changeColor = (event) => {
    const modelViewer = document.querySelector("model-viewer");
    modelViewer.variantName = event.target.value;
  };

  const [currentSrc, setCurrentSrc] = useState(product.src);

  return (*/HTML/*)
}
```

```html
<div className="accordion">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="Lacquer" className="accordion__input" />
    <label htmlFor="Lacquer" className="materialLabel">Lacquer</label>
    <div className="items">
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value='Ballet Pink'>Ballet Pink</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Bellini Peach">Bellini Peach</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Boeing Navy">Boeing Navy</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Cessna Grey">Cessna Grey</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Charter Coral">Charter Coral</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Cirrus White">Cirrus White</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Citation Blue">Citation Blue</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Dash Pink">Dash Pink</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Falcon Grey">Falcon Grey</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Gulfstream Blue">Gulfstream Blue</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Havilland Sage">Havilland Sage</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Illuminating Yellow">Illuminating Yellow</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Lear Green">Lear Green</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Merlin Lavender">Merlin Lavender</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Midnight Green">Midnight Green</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Polar Ice">Polar Ice</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Smoky Blue">Smoky Blue</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Stratos Black">Stratos Black</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Vitamin C">Vitamin C</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" id="Wood" className="accordion__input" />
    <label htmlFor="Wood" className="materialLabel">Wood</label>
    <div className="items">
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Golden Pecan Mappa Burl">Golden Pecan Mappa Burl</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Golden Pecan Olive Ash">Golden Pecan Olive Ash</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Natural Mappa Burl">Natural Mappa Burl</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Natural Olive Ash">Natural Olive Ash</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Provincial Mappa Burl">Provincial Mappa Burl</button>
      <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value="Provincial Olive Ash">Provincial Olive Ash</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now I can console.log(product.material) and see the product JSON, but I am unsure how to extract that information and plug it into a

Here is the redux/axios portion I use to getProductDetails:

```js
export const getProductDetails = (id) => async(dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST});
    
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
    
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ?
        error.response.data.message :
        error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: after fetching the array of data use map method on it...which state are your fetched data?

Comment: @Ebay I'm sorry, what do you mean by which state is my data fetched? I'm fairly new to using a fullstack workflow, so I am unsure. I use the `useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails` the `getProductDetails` is from redux/axios in a folder called actions, I've updated my question on how I do that with redux/axios. Hopefully that answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom component for simplicity representing your input radio and loop

1. The list of `materials` object
2. The list of values inside it

In `ProductScreen`:

```
{
  product && product.materials[0].map((material) => (
    <CustomRadioButton material={material} changeColor={changeColor} />
  ));
}
```

Create a new `CustomRadioButton` component

```
export const CustomRadioButton = ({ material, changeColor }) => {
  const materialName = Object.keys(material);
  if (!materialName) return <></>;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='accordion'
        id={materialName}
        className='accordion__input'
      />
      <label htmlFor={materialName} className='materialLabel'>
        {materialName}
      </label>
      <div className='items'>
        {material[materialName].map((item) => (
          <button onClick={changeColor} className='item' value={item}>
            {item}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help! I will test this out here shortly and report back!

Comment: Alright, I've been playing around with it for about an hour now, and I keep getting either `"somehting".map is not a function` or `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Any idea what could be causing this? In the mean time, I'm going to keep playing around with it and see what I can figure out! Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I was also able to figure out how to console.log my materials finally with your help, so thank you for that. If it helps you at all, it's `console.log((product.materials)[0].Lacquer[0])` and that will give me the first lacquer color in the array.

Comment: @WadeMorrison Try to change the code as in the edited answer.

Comment: Okay I tried the changed code above, as well as what I messed with last night from the old code. And for some reason I keep getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` on the `<ProductScreen>` which is odd because as I said earlier I can console.log it just fine? So I'm still tinkering around with it, thank you again for the help! I think it's getting closer haha

Comment: Ayyyyye, I got it! Well sort of anyways. I had to remove the `[0]` from `...product && product.materials[0].map((material)...` if I include that it says it can't read property "0", however, the only problem now is that when I go to reload the page or navigate to a different product, it throws an error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`
I tried putting the src's in a const instead of importing them from axios/getProductDetails and it works, so I was thinking, is it having trouble because `product` is inside of curly braces?

Comment: Okay I got that figured out now! I will post below with what worked for me. And I will still upvote your answer as I am sure it could help someone else with a different scenario! Thank you so much for the help and getting me pointed into the right direction! Now on to the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the help of @LuccaPizzini I was able to figure out how to make it work!
Here is what I had to do instead:

In `Product Screen`:

```html
{
  product && (product.materials ||).map((material, index) => (
    <CustomRadioButton key={index} material={material} changeColor={changeColor} />
  ))
}
```

Create a new `CustomRadioButton` component:

```html
export const CustomRadioButton = ({ material, changeColor }) => {
  const materialName = Object.keys(material);
  if (!materialName) return <></>;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type='radio'
        name='accordion'
        id={materialName}
        className='accordion__input'
      />
      <label htmlFor={materialName} className='materialLabel'>
        {materialName}
      </label>
      <div className='items'>
        {material[materialName].map((item) => (
          <button key={item} onClick={changeColor} className='item' value={item}>
            {item}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Essentially, very small changes in both components from what he had provided.